# W3C setting new attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a jQuery slider that requires I add new attributes to the img tag so it can display the description and a link. However this is not W3C compliant.

Is there a way to make it pass?

```
<img src="..." alt="..." data-text-id="#sliderText" data-title="..." data-desc="..." />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your doctype to be HTML 5. Use this code at the top of your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 4):

That is W3C compliant, but only in HTML5. Make sure your DOCTYPE is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the doctype to - `<!doctype html>`

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't the w3c validator, you can use http://html5.validator.nu/, to validate it. I have seen it mentioned before

Comment: The W3C validator does have HTML5 support too, although it is "experimental".