# Site accessibility (indexing) from google - doctype transitional versus doctype html

Tags: html, xhtml, accessibility, doctype, xhtml-transitional

Im having a discussion with one my friends about doctype transitional versus doctype html.
The subject is accessibility for google and potentially screen readers (which you could find blind people using).

We're arguing whether having a website build / declared with doctype "transitional" would rank and index better with google than a website build / declared with doctype "html".

Are there any downsides in terms of building your website with doctype "html" when in it comes to google?

My friend would rather stick with transitional, because you can validate that at w3.org and that's it's more or less "standard" where I would rather want to use some of the new technologies to achieve better visual effect and rendering.

Comment: I can't imagine how this would matter to a ranking system. Links in, links out, textual analysis of the words on the page, acknowledgement of the ads on the page and their relative view-to-click ratios. The doctype of the page shouldn't be of concern. Google can index and rank some pretty in-valid pages

Answer (score 1):

Screen readers do not interprit the DOCTYPES differently. However I would say you should either pick the HTML 4 Strict or the HTML 5 DOCTYPE. The HTML 4 Transitional doctype was really meant for people to use when they were moving from HTML 3 to 4, and either a) they are saying *whoa cool HTML 4 I am just testing this out* or b) *Yeah, we want to move to HTML4, we want to use the cool new  features of 4.0 and we can't really recode out site at this time.* Note we are talking pre-2000 here, so a lot of people who code these days couldn't probably say I know the differences between HTML 3, and 4/4.01.

W3C for validating HTML 5 is still getting worked on. See my answer on [W3C setting new attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10835309/1276124)

Re Google: You probably could write/code your site in HTML 3 or even 2 and it would still get indexed. AFAK Google still relies on headings (`<h1>-<h6>`) as part of ranking. Headings were introduced in HTML 2 or 3.

Comment: Actually headings are even earlier than HTML 2. They appear in the first public description of HTML from 1992. This one: http://www.w3.org/History/19921103-hypertext/hypertext/WWW/MarkUp/Tags.html

Comment: I almost wanted to say v1, but didn't research it.